# How is Angular 2 lighter than Angular 1?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2. I've just created new starter project using `angular-cli` and done `ng build --prod`. I've got a `dist` folder 8.2 Mb.
Here's the output:

[image]

I have **three** questions:

- What files do I actually need?
- What else can be done to minimize the size?
- Is it possible to fetch `gzipped` files in `HTML` page as if they
  were regular scripts? I mean, would it be valid `<script  src='...script.gz'></script>`?

Comment: even I don't understand. There are lots of files in angular2 which I see in network tab that gets downloads. Framework have lots of dependencies. Setting up an angular 1 project was much easier than angular 2.

Answer (score 6):

- Don't measure the number of files loaded during development. With Angular2 and TS you have a build step and for size measurement, only the output of the build step is relevant
- A big difference between A1 and A2 is that A1 can work without loading an Angular library into the browser. When AoT (ahead of time compilation) is used, the Angular2 components templates are processed and JS generated for bindings, therefore no Angular library that loads, parses and compiles, and processes components templates is necessary.

  - This build step and AoT also allow tree-shaking across the whole code base
- Change detection is working completely different.

  - Through the use of zones, Angular2 is much more efficienct in detecting when change detection needs to be done.
  - Because of the unidirectional data flow Angular can limit the scope of where change detection needs to happen within the DOM tree.
  - Using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and other measures allow the developer to further restrict where and when change detection needs to run

The Angular2 team is still working on further optimize all kinds of things and I'm sure there is quite some room for further improvements.